# Right Justifying output stream in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working in C++.  I'm given a 10 digit string (char array) that may or may not have 3 dashes in it (making it up to 13 characters).  Is there a built in way with the stream to right justify it?

How would I go about printing to the stream right justified?  Is there a built in function/way to do this, or do I need to pad 3 spaces into the beginning of the character array?

I'm dealing with ostream to be specific, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to use [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) in conjunction with [`std::right`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void)
{
   std::cout << std::right << std::setw(13) << "foobar" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: It is *important* that you do the `<< right << setw(13)` right before the thing you want to format. I.e. if you're doing `cout << "added " << 5 << " files" << endl;`, you can't just do `cout << right << setw(13) << "added " ...` at the start. You *must* do it right before the number, at least on MacOS X.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. You can use `setw()` to set the width. The default justification is right-justified, and the default padding is space, so this will add spaces to the left.

```
stream << setw(13) << yourString
```

See: [`setw()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/). You'll need to include `<iomanip>`.

Answer (score 6):

See "setw" and "right" in your favorite C++ (iostream) reference for further details:

```
 cout << setw(13) << right << your_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a unique answer, but an additional "gotcha" that I discovered and is too long for a comment...

All the formatting stuff is only applied *once* to `yourString`.  Anything additional, like `<< yourString2` doesn't abide by the same formatting rules.  For instance if I want to right-justify **two** strings and pad 24 asterisks (easier to see) to the left, this doesn't work:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::string h = "hello ";
std::string t = "there";
oss << std::right << std::setw(24) << h << t;
std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
// this outputs
******************hello there
```

That will apply the correct padding to `"hello "` *only* (that's 18 asterisks, making the entire width including the trailing space 24 long), and *then* `"there"` gets tacked on at the end, making the end result longer than I wanted.  Instead, I wanted

```
*************hello there
```

Not sure if there's another way (you could simply redo the formatting I'm sure), but I found it easiest to simply combine the two strings into one:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::string h = "hello ";
std::string t = "there";
// + concatenates t onto h, creating one string
oss << std::right << std::setw(24) << h + t;
std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
// this outputs
*************hello there
```

The whole output is 24 long like I wanted.

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4YKe4jh9)